# Is it possible to calculate a divs width after its been created?

Tags: html, css

I have a number of `div`s generated with PHP, I want the widths of the `div`s to be even (i.e. 2 = 50%, 3 = 33%, 4 = 25%, etc) no matter how many `div`s are made.

I would like to do this with CSS, is it possible?

```css
.container {
  margin: 10px 0;
  width: 100%;
}
.container div {
  height: 50px;
}
.container div:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: red;
}
.container div:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: blue;
}
.twoColumns,
.threeColumns,
.fourColumns {
  height: 50px;
}
.twoColumns div,
.threeColumns div,
.fourColumns div {
  float: left;
}
.twoColumns div {
  width: 50%;
}
.threeColumns div {
  width: 33.333333333%;
}
.fourColumns div {
  width: 25%;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>Example markup</h1>
  <strong>This would be two columns:</strong>
  <div class="container">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
  <strong>This would be three columns:</strong>
  <div class="container">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
  <strong>This would be four columns:</strong>
  <div class="container">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  <h1>Desired result (using set widths)</h1>
  <strong>This is two columns:</strong>
  <div class="container twoColumns">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
  <strong>This is three columns:</strong>
  <div class="container threeColumns">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
  <strong>This is four columns:</strong>
  <div class="container fourColumns">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Just create your css class and add the css class at the right div when you create them...

Comment: Why don't you fixe size from php?

Comment: @GuillaumeKiz - lets just say I cant.

Comment: if php makes 2, then the width is going to be 50%, but then if it adds another one, then the third is going to be 33%, but the first two are going to be 50% still.

Comment: @Alexis : that won't work. Because div's are created dynamically, there can be any number of div's.

Comment: @MarcHoover I've modified your question to add some examples as while I understood what you were after your original version could be open to interpretation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Flexbox can be used to make elements the same width:

- Add `display: flex;` to the containing element to make all its children use the flexbox model
- Add `flex: 1;` to the child elements to allow them to stretch/constrict as required

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 10px 0;
  width: 100%;
}
.container div {
  flex: 1;
}
.container div:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: red;
}
.container div:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Actually, i see the problem, and what i need is the child div's to break and start a new column after say 10 child divs.

Comment: @MarcHoover You have a slight issue with your markup in that you are opening `div`s but closing `span`s (i.e. `<div>Text</span>`. Fixing this will result in the desired behaviour http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bZkyWB.

Comment: Yeah, i noticed that after i posted. It ALMOST works, but i need a line break (<br>) after every child div, but when i add it, it doesnt line break, any suggestions?

Comment: @MarcHoover Hmm, I'm not sure I follow exactly what you are trying to achieve, if you are looking to add a break after every `div` then they would no longer be in columns. Using the flexbox model means that `<br/>`s will not work, you could achieve a similar result by adding `flex-wrap: wrap;` to the container and `flex: 1 0 100%;` to the desired child http://codepen.io/anon/pen/AXwkQd

Comment: Basically like craigslist has it: https://orlando.craigslist.org/

On the "community" & "for sale", its 2 columns, and "discussion forums" its 3 - mostly depending on how many links they have underneath.

Comment: @MarcHoover You could use a `span` as a breaking element and give it a flex basis of 100% to force the lines to wrap by adding `.container span {flex: 1 0 100%;}` http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JKzqZQ.